# Using 'base' keyword in delegate causes System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a weird problem and I would like if someone can enlighten me on why is this happening. I have a protected method in a base abstract class as following:

```
protected T ForExistingEntity<T>(TEntity entity, object key, Func<Entity, T> action) {
    entity = GetByKey(key);
    if (entity != null)
        return action(entity);

    return default(T); 
}
```

My original call from an inherited class was as follows:

```
return base.ForExistingEntity(
    new MyEntity(), key, e => {
        e.someFiled = 5;
        return base.Update(e);
    }
);
```

When this code executes, an exception get raised at the line that reads:

```
return action(entity);
```

in the base abstract class. The exception is:

System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Now when I modify my call as following:

```
return base.ForExistingEntity(
    new MyEntity(), key, e => {
        e.someFiled = 5;
        return Update(e);
    }
);
```

it runs normally without any issues.

**Edit:**

The Update method is located in the base abstract class and looks like this:

```
public virtual bool Update(TEntity entity) {
    Condition.Requires(entity, "entity")
        .IsNotNull();

    if (ValidateEntity(entity))
        return Update(entity, true);

    return false;
}
```

I am starting to think that this is happening because of Update being virtual and the call actually originates in the base class itself? The exception isn't very helpfull anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a [known C# compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/626550/badimageformatexception-on-simple-program-using-generics-and-lambdas) involving calling a base virtual method from an anonymous method within a generic class. Don't hesitate to upvote this bug on connect if you want it solved. Fortunately, the workaround is quite simple here.

Comment: I just ran into the same bug. It still has not been solved by MS, but it can be worked around by creating a method to wrap the base method call.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had .NET 4.5 framework installed. When I uninstalled this and replaced with .NET 4.0 framework, this problem went away (i.e. 4.0.30319 when I look at the top right corner of my VS2010 info)