# Compiler generated incorrect code for anonymous methods [MS BUG FIXED]

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, cil, anonymous-methods

See the following code:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual void Foo<T>() where T : class
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Foo<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("derived");
    }

    public void Bang()
    {
        Action bang = new Action(delegate { base.Foo<string>(); });
        bang();    //VerificationException is thrown
    }
}
```

`new Derived().Bang();` throws an exception. Inside the generated CIL of the method `Bang` I got:

```
call instance void ConsoleApp.Derived::'<>n__FabricatedMethod1'<string>()
```

and the signature of the compiler generated method:

```
method private hidebysig 
    instance void '<>n__FabricatedMethod1'<T> () cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )       
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance void ConsoleApp.Base::Foo<!!T>()
    IL_0006: ret
}
```

I think the correct code should be `'<>n__FabricatedMethod1'<class T>`. Is it a bug?
By the way, without using `delegate{ }`(lambda expression is the same), the code works fine with syntax sugars.

```
Action good = new Action(base.Foo<string>());
good();  //fine
```

**EDIT** I'm using VS2012 RTMRel in windows8 RTM, .net framework 4.5

**EDIT** This bug is now fixed.

Comment: Your code works for me. Which version of C#/.Net/Visual Studio are you using? Which platform are you targeting?

Comment: @jeroenh: C# 4.5 VS2012.

Comment: I tried with VS2010, C# 4 and 3.5. Don't have access to 2012 right now but will certainly try it tonight.

Comment: Confirmed on VS2012. Gets a 'type argument 'T' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.' which is interesting.

Comment: Output from PEVerify indicates the compiler has indeed a bug... `[IL]: Error: [ConsoleApplication3.exe : ConsoleApplication3.Derived::<>n__FabricatedMethod1[T]][
offset 0x00000001] Unable to resolve token.
1 Error(s) Verifying ConsoleApplication3.exe`

Comment: @leppie: LOL I'm just doing the same thing.

Comment: I think, based on the comments so far, you can fairly safely say you've found a bug, and answer your own question with that. The only way in which this could be anything other than a compiler bug is if the language specification doesn't allow `base` method calls in delegates (I haven't checked), but even then, the lack of a proper diagnostic is a missing desirable feature in the compiler. (Do report it to Microsoft, of course.)

Comment: BTW, if you remove the `where T : class` constraint from the virtual method. The code verifies, and runs correctly.

Comment: `where T : struct` also fails, but `where T : IComparable` or `where T : Base` works. Edit: `where T : new()` also fails.

Comment: @leppie: Reported to MS, ticket number: 766845

Comment: @DannyChen: :) I added a link back to here for reference.

Comment: This seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290559/using-base-keyword-in-delegate-causes-system-badimageformatexception, although that caused `BadImageFormatException` and MS claims it has been fixed.

Comment: I find this strange. Isn't the delegate there whether you explicitly use the delegate keyword or not? I thought the two syntaxes were equivalent and am therefore surprised they could lead to different IL unless the actual *parsing* had a bug with more far-reaching consequences.

Comment: @TheDag Doesn't the delegate { } syntax create an extra anonymous method that then calls Foo, where as new Action(base.Foo<string>) calls Foo directly without the extra indirection?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to plaster the link and the fixed status all over the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is confirmed as a bug and [now fixed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766845/vs2012-the-compiler-generated-incorrect-codes-for-anonymous-methods)

Update: the Connect article no longer exists.  The bug is fixed.

Comment: Pity we will never know when this will reach us. Microsoft should really communicate better on that site...

Answer (score 1):

At first - This is a possible way how to fix this, but probably not an answer to your question. (But comments don´t have code formating)

I believe this is similar to this: [Outer Variable Trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416758/outer-variable-trap), because you are using Foo() method as a variable and there is a bug (or maybe a feature) in .NET

I have tried to change Bang() method to this

```
public void Bang()
{
    Action baseMethod = base.Foo<string>;
    Action bang = new Action(delegate { baseMethod(); });
    bang();    //VerificationException is thrown
}
```

And it works and the result is "base"

I hope it helps a little bit.

Comment: FYI, Comments *do* have code formatting, you just can't include line breaks and are still limited by the total number of characters (which includes markdown)