# BadImageFormatException in lambda with base call

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiler generated incorrect code for anonymous methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813535/compiler-generated-incorrect-code-for-anonymous-methods)

Why following code cause `BadImageFormatException`?

```c#
public static void Main()
{
    var c = new Child();
    Console.WriteLine(c.Something());
}

public class Base<T>
{
    public virtual T Something()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class Child : Base<int>
{
    public override int Something()
    {
        //return base.Something(); //This one works well

        //Func<int> func = base.Something;
        //func(); //Works well too

        Func<int> func = () => base.Something();
        return func(); //BadImageFormatException
    }
}
```

`BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`

.NET 4.0. Both x64 and x86 machines.

**UPD.** Waiting for response from MS. [Ticket #768801](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768801/using-base-qualifier-in-anonymous-method-causing-badimageformatexception)

Comment: What happens if you assign an explicitly-declared instance method to `func` instead of a lambda?

Comment: @AdamRobinson Just added to sample - it works well.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant; I mean within `Child` declare the following function: `private int SomethingXX { return base.Something(); }` then do `func = SomethingXX;`

Comment: @AdamRobinson Works. Fails only if ``base`` in lambda.

Comment: Actually, this issue has been brought up before, will look for it. It is .NET 4.5 related.

Comment: It affects 4.0 as well. In 3.5, you'll get a compiler warning: "Access to member ... through a 'base' keyword from an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression or iterator results in unverifiable code. Consider moving the access to a helper method on the containing type."

Comment: @leppie Code from that issue works on .net 4.0 with vs2010. Just checked.

Comment: I dont get how Func<int> can be returned when return type is int

Comment: @nawfal: the `Func<int>` is called before return.

Comment: @leppie oh yes just noticed. +1